# How can I be alerted when a process goes idle (that is, its CPU usage reaches zero for a sustained period on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, process, monitoring, cpu-usage, alert

How can I be alerted when a process goes idle (that is, its CPU usage reaches zero for a sustained period on Windows 7?

Essentially, I have a long running batch process that is pegging one of the cores. While I am able to work on other tasks, I sometime forget to check if it has finished. Is there a way I can be alerted when it is finished by monitoring the processes CPU usage?

Comment: Can you run this process from a batch script, and then add a line that will throw up a dialog box>

Comment: @soandos Yep, but it has to work on Win 7.

Comment: and what is wrong with a .bat file or VB Script file (.vbs, just paste http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/how-can-i-open-a-message-box-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Because I don't want to have to start the process from a batch file. These are long running processes that I interact with via a GUI, then wait for completion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using SNMP to monitor CPU usage and send a trap when it goes idle; or whatever you want ?